# Android app crashes after launching intent and using setText() in TextView

Tags: java, android, android-intent, crash

I'm trying to launch an activity using intents and setting values in TextViews in the launched activity, but when I try to do that my app crashes. Heres the activity I'm trying to launch. It crashes when i try to set the text in the last two code lines

```
public class GameOver extends Activity {

  TextView correctTxt;
  TextView incorrectTxt;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      Intent intent = getIntent();
      int correct = intent.getIntExtra("correct", 0);
      int incorrect = intent.getIntExtra("incorrect", 0);

      correctTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.correct_txt);
      incorrectTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.incorrect_txt);

      correctTxt.setText("" + correct);
      incorrectTxt.setText("" + incorrect);
  }
}
```

And the activity that's launching. I make use of the intent in the trueButton onClickListener method:

```
package com.example.beithia.geotest;

import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.*;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;


public class TestActivity extends Activity {

  private Button trueButton;
  private Button falseButton;
  private TextView questionTextView;
  private TextView correctNum;
  private TextView incorrectNum;
  private TextView avgScore;
  int numOfCorrect = 0;
  int numOfIncorrect = 0;
  double num = 1;

  private TrueFalse[] questionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia,true),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_channel_islands,true),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_china,false),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mexico,true),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_turkey,false),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_everest,false),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_colombia,false),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_vatican,true),
    new TrueFalse(R.string.question_nile,true),
  };

  private int currentIndex = 0;

  private void updateQuestion() {
    int question = questionBank[currentIndex].getQuestion();
    questionTextView.setText(question);
  }

  private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = questionBank[currentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
    int msgId = 0;
    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        msgId = R.string.correct_toast;
        numOfCorrect++;
    }
    else {
        msgId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        numOfIncorrect++;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,msgId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    questionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    correctNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.correct_num);
    incorrectNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.incorrect_num);
    avgScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.average_score);


    trueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    trueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          checkAnswer(true);
          double score = (numOfCorrect / num) * 100;
          currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % questionBank.length;
          correctNum.setText("Correct: " + numOfCorrect);
          incorrectNum.setText("Incorrect: " + numOfIncorrect);
          avgScore.setText("Score: " + String.format("%.2f", score) + "%");
          updateQuestion();
          num++;
          if(num > 10) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, GameOver.class);
            intent.putExtra("correct", numOfCorrect);
            intent.putExtra("incorrect", numOfIncorrect);
            startActivity(intent);
          }

      }

    });
    falseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    falseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          checkAnswer(false);
          double score = (numOfCorrect / num) * 100;
          currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % questionBank.length;
          correctNum.setText("Correct: " + numOfCorrect);
          incorrectNum.setText("Incorrect: " + numOfIncorrect);
          avgScore.setText("Score: " + String.format("%.2f", score) + "%");
          updateQuestion();
          num++;

        }

    });

    updateQuestion();
  }
}
```

Here's the layout for activity_main.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/correct_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff12" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/incorrect_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffff5440" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/average_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffff8c1a" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button"/>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/false_button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/false_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the layout for the activity_game_over.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/correct_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/incorrect_txt"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I can get it to work if I use the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);`
however when I try to launch the main activity again it starts the GameOver Activity, but it should start the GeoQuiz activity instead.

Comment: Can you post your manifest also.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `GameOver` activity you don't set any content view `setContentView()`, hence you textViews cannot be found, `findViewById` returns `null`, hence you get NullPointerException when invoking `setText()`.

Comment: I tried doing that with   setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over); it works when I do that, however when I try to launch the app from the main activity it just launches the GameOver activity again. Do i need to reset the setContentView()? its like it is just storing the view from the GameOver activity once it is called through the intent.

Comment: @maobe this line helps get rid of the NPE and app crashes. Which activity is launched first is defined in the app manifest. `setContentView()` just associates a layout with activity, you don't need to "reset" it.

Answer (score 0):

> I can get it to work if I use the setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over); however when I try to launch the main activity again it starts the GameOver Activity, but it should start the GeoQuiz activity instead. Please help!

The activity that runs at start up is defined in the android manifest xml file of your project.

look for
action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"

Comment: Then I guess you are setting off the onClick you made in the onCreate... Or possibly you never close the gameover activity, so its still open when you come back to the app

Comment: Activities stay open and just pause by default upon exiting the program

Comment: I've never done anything with closing the activity. maybe thats the issue? I'm new to Android. How do I go about closing it?

Comment: finish(); you obviously can't put this in the onCreate or your activity well just open and close